# Error in installing a cocoapod into my xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have just started learning how to use cocoapods in my xcode projects. I have version 1.1.1 installed onto my computer. Following tutorials, I have done the exact same thing as others have but not getting the correct response.

After getting a podfile in my project, this is what I did.

```js
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'podTester' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for podTester

        pod 'SDWebImage'

  target 'podTesterTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'podTesterUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

After typing pod install in my terminal, it gives me something like this. (unlike that in the tutorial)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/970Cq.png)

After that, I go into my new swift file (the white one), my project gets messed up and the directory now looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvHdF.png)

Pretty much my project disappears and only the pod file remains.

I am just wondering what has gone wrong and how I can fix it. Thanks so much!

Comment: I assume all your code is still present in Finder? Are you certain you are opening the Xcode Workspace now instead of the Xcode Project?

Comment: I am opening my Xcode Workspace... If I open my Xcode project, my code is still there. But in the Xcode workspace sidebar (consisting all the components to it), there are two files with icons like the Xcode Project. The first one is called podTester.xcodeproj with no sub files. The second is called pods with all the things my pod consists of. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't exactly know the issue. I would delete the workspace and pods and try again using `pod install`. Make sure you have the latest stable version of cocoapods. Also, simplifying your Podfile as a test could help, by getting rid of the testing targets.